# ¿Cómo es el ciclo de vida de Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Hace poco que estoy programando en Xamarin.forms y hay algunas cosas que no entiendo.

Yo sé que en Android existen los métodos `OnCreate()`, `OnStart()`, `OnResume()`, `OnPause()`, `OnStop()` y `OnDestroy()` y estos cumplen el ciclo de vida de Android.

En mi App Estoy llamando a una ventana que al terminar su función se cierra y vuelve a la ventana anterior... lo que me gustaría hacer es utilizar el método `OnResume()` para que haga algo en particular cuando vuelve a esta ventana.

**Ventana1:**

```
private void BtnNavegar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((NavigationPage)this.Parent).PushAsync(new Ventana2());
}
```

**Ventana2:**

```
private void BtnFinalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Acá cumple su funcion
    Navigation.PopAsync(); //Acá cierra la ventana 2
}
```

**En resumen:**

Cuando en la ventana 2 hago el `Navigation.PopAsync();` vuelve a la ventana 1 y quiero que al volver se ejecute lo que sería el `OnResume()` de Android.

Existe la forma de hacerlo en Xamarin.forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única forma que encontré de resolver esto es con `OnAppearing()` que basicamente hace que apenas aparezca la ventana se ejecute el código que tiene dentro.

Aquí dejo un [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210120195429/http://geekswithblogs.net/benko/archive/2014/12/17/working-with-xamarin-forms-and-authentication.aspx) para que puedan ver cómo funciona...